# Ruby - NoMethodError when subtracting dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby newbie - I am trying to define a variable called `days_to_exp` that will count the number of days until the expiration date on a perishable food item. I've placed the following method in a serializer:

```
class ItemSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
attributes :id, :food_name, :purchase_date, :exp_date, :store_name, :quantity, :purchased, :days_to_exp

  def days_to_exp
    today = Time.now.utc.to_date
    exp_dte = exp_date
    (exp_dte - today).to_i
  end
end
```

Error: NameError (undefined local variable or method `exp_date' for #):

Could anyone help me understand why this error has occurred? Thank you!

Comment: Remove the : to get the value

Comment: You made a typo. It should be `exp_dte = exp_date`. Read error messages. The word `Symbol` really stands out...

Comment: Try using `exp_date` instead of `:exp_date`.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I should have realized that. I've edited the original post. Getting a new error now though...

Answer (score 1):

`exp_date` is an attribute of the model. So, you can just write:

```
object.exp_date - today
```

The line at the top of the class, which states:

```
attributes :exp_date
```

is just defining the attribute - which does things like creating getter/setter methods for it. Don't confuse the [`Symbol`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html) with variables/methods.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I'm definitely mixing up symbols with variables/methods. I tried to edit the post and reflect your answer, but I am getting a new error now...